# Adding significance brackets on graph with multiple x labels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a clustered bar chart with two x-axis levels. I would like to add two significance brackets to indicate there is a significant difference between the Active and Sham groups at 1 month post (bracket 1: between Active 1 Month post and Sham 1 Month post) and at 3 months post (bracket 2: between Active 3 months post and Sham 3 months post).

However, I cannot figure out how to extend the bracket from one bar cluster to the other as you can see below. Is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Here is my sample data:

```
results <- dput(results)
structure(list(tdcs = c("active", "active", "active", "active", 
"active", "active", "sham", "sham", "sham", "sham", "sham", "sham"
), type = c("Trained Words", "Trained Words", "Untrained Words", 
"Untrained Words", "Comprehension", "Comprehension", "Trained Words", 
"Trained Words", "Untrained Words", "Untrained Words", "Comprehension", 
"Comprehension"), chgacc = c(0.693669355, 0.512145161, 0.189221837, 
0.19727383, 0.488085538, 0.080855379, 0.365701923, 0.331008065, 
-0.405006036, -0.210909879, -0.135833333, 0.006145503), grouping = c("Active: 1 Month Post", 
"Active: 3 Months Post", "Active: 1 Month Post", "Active: 3 Months Post", 
"Active: 1 Month Post", "Active: 3 Months Post", "Sham: 1 Month Post", 
"Sham: 3 Months Post", "Sham: 1 Month Post", "Sham: 3 Months Post", 
"Sham: 1 Month Post", "Sham: 3 Months Post"), time = c("1 Month Post", 
"3 Months Post", "1 Month Post", "3 Months Post", "1 Month Post", 
"3 Months Post", "1 Month Post", "3 Months Post", "1 Month Post", 
"3 Months Post", "1 Month Post", "3 Months Post")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(tdcs = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), chgacc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), grouping = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

And my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

results$type <- as.factor(results$type)


colorpicks <- c("darkslategray", "azure3","blue3", "cyan")


plotexample <- results %>%
  dplyr::filter(type == "Trained Words") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = chgacc, fill = grouping)) +
  theme_minimal_hgrid()+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~tdcs, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x" ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorpicks, labels = c('Active - 1 Month Post','Active - 3 Months Post',
                                                    'Sham - 1 Month Post', 'Sham - 3 Months Post'))+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0,"lines"),
      strip.background = element_blank(),
      strip.placement = "outside")+

  geom_signif(y_position = c(0.8,0.6), xmin = c(1,2), 
              xmax = c(4,6), annotation = c("*"),
              tip_length = 0.1)+
  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1),limits = (c(-.2,.8))) +
  labs(x = "Stimulation Type", y = "Mean Accuracy \nChange from Baseline", fill = 'Stimulation Type & \nTime Point')+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 16), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0, hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=11))
plotexample
```